# Spring security 403 forbidden error keeps happening even with csrf disable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, http-status-code-403

I've been following a tutorial from https://programmingtechie.com/2019/11/08/build-a-full-stack-reddit-clone-with-spring-boot-and-angular-part-3/.

And for some reason, `/auth/api/login` REST-API keeps throwing 403 forbidden error (Access denied) even when I disabled csrf.

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

This is on the `SecurityConfig` class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Below is the `AuthController`.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;
    private final RefreshTokenService refreshTokenService;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup (@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        authService.signup(registerRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User Registration Successful", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public AuthenticationResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        return authService.login(loginRequest);
    }

    @GetMapping("accountVerification/{token}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> verifyAccount(@PathVariable String token) {
        authService.verifyAccount(token);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Account Activated Successfully", OK);
    }
```

When I try requesting `http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup`, it works just fine but  `http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login` keeps returning 403 forbidden error.

To be clear, below is the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` class.

```java
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtProvider.validateToken(jwt)){
            String username = jwtProvider.getUsernameFromJwt(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                    null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if(StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }

        return bearerToken;
    }
```

Can somebody point out the mistakes or is there more configuration that I need to do?

Comment: Did you try with .antMatchers("/auth/api/**") in security config ?

Comment: As you are able to perform the /signup, /login should work, make sure you have entered the correct credentials and have used password encoder as required (might be Bcypt)

Comment: Note that Spring Security ships with built-in support for JWTs, so the simplest way is likely to consult the Resource Server [1] and JWT Login [2] samples. [1] - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server, [2] - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login

Answer (score 3):

Fix : Remove cors() from the HttpSecurity Configuration.

I faced the same issue while following this tutorial. To be frank even i am new to new spring-boot. Was trying out different methods to solve this, and this one clicked for me. I am not sure why this solves the issue. Need to dig in on this one. But i hope this one helps you to  move forward in this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. There are kinds of reasons to make this happen. After I tried what others said, it still can't be resolved. If you are still stumbled by  the similar issue. **Try to debug it, find the root cause by your self.**
Here's my steps what I did,

**1. Drop a breakpoint on the line set the 403 status, to see how this happen from the stackframes.**

Guess that it returns 403 without much other information, but it must need to set the status to the response, right? So drop a breakpoint to the setStatus method, I don't know where it should locate, in tomcat lib, spring lib, or servlet lib. Check the `HttpResponse`, they're several implementation, set the breakpoints for those setStatus/setCode methods. (Next you can see it acutally happens at `HttpResponseWrapper::setStatus`)

**2. Analyze the stackframes to see what's going on there**

After the breakpoint got hit, the stackframes show very clear.
Here's what I got with VS Code when the breakpoint is hitting:

```
HttpServletResponseWrapper.setStatus(int) (\javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar\javax.servlet.http\HttpServletResponseWrapper.class:201)
CorsFilter.handleInvalidCORS(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse,FilterChain) (\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar\org.apache.catalina.filters\CorsFilter.class:376)
CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse,FilterChain) (\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar\org.apache.catalina.filters\CorsFilter.class:252)
CorsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest,ServletResponse,FilterChain) (\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar\org.apache.catalina.filters\CorsFilter.class:168)
GeneratedMethodAccessor141.invoke(Object,Object[]) (Unknown Source:-1)
```

You can see the root reason is CorsFilter, which I find the allow origin doesn't set. After setting the `cors.allowed.origins` field, the issue just gone.
Hope you can resolve your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but for my case, I misspelled my password attributes in LoginRequest class. this is what it looks like:

```
public class LoginRequest{
  private String username;
  private String passsword; // i put 3's'
}
```

then in my request body from postman as you can see they did not match because of the spelling:

```
{
  "username":"name"
  "password":"123" // i put 2 's'
}
```

and whenever i run this i got the same error.

I'm also new to this.. but understanding the response will actually help you a lot,
I hope it helps others that facing the same issue.