# Spring boot api gives 403 forbidden error

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot application with a mongo databse and spring security as a dependency.
It has two services first one for authentication and second one for application resource (entities, services controllers).
This is my config class in the authentication  service:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
@Bean
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new MongoUserDetailsService();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    System.out.println("auth");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
}

@Bean(name="authenticationManager")
@Lazy
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
}
```

this is the rest controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

//Getting all users
@GetMapping(value = "")
public List<UserDTO> getAllUsers() {
    return userServiceImpl.getAllUsers();
    
}

//Getting a user by ID
@GetMapping(value = "/profil/{userId}")
public UserDTO getUserById(@PathVariable String userId) {
    return userServiceImpl.getUserById(userId);
}

//Getting a user by Username
@GetMapping(value = "/profil/username/{username}")
public UserDTO getUserByUsernameOrEmail(String username) {
    return userServiceImpl.getUserByUsernameOrEmail(username);
}

//Logout user and delete token
@PostMapping("/logout")
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
     userServiceImpl.logout(request);
    
}
```

I changed my configure method to this :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests() // authorize
    .anyRequest().authenticated() // all requests are authenticated
    .and()
    .httpBasic();

    http.cors();
    
}
```

Now i get 401 unauthorized when acceccing protected resources.The problem is now even when i send the correct bearer token in the request header i still get 401 unauthorized "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Update:
I changed my project architecture from microservices to one simple spring boot project.
this is the new code of the class  "AuthServerSecurityConfig"

```
@Configuration
public class AuthServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
@Bean
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new MongoUserDetailsService();
}

@Autowired
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .anonymous().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll().and()
    .httpBasic();

    http.cors();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
}

@Bean(name="authenticationManager")
@Lazy
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
}
```

and this "ResourceServerConfig" code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("foo").tokenServices(tokenServices);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        http
        .authorizeRequests() // authorize
        .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll();
        
        http
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
        
        http
        .headers().addHeaderWriter(new HeaderWriter() {
        @Override
        public void writeHeaders(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method"));
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

When i try to access protected resource i get "error": "unauthorized",
"error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource", Which is the normal behaviour.The problem is now i can't login to get the user aceess_token.

I get  "401 unauthorized" when accessing this endpoint "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=user".

These are the default init user credentials and the user exists in my mongodatabase with a crypted and correct format password starts with "$2a" and has "60" caracters.

I get in "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
Authentication failed: password does not match stored value" in the console when trying to login.

Comment: What do you have in your rest controller? Any `@PreAuthorize` annotations?

Comment: i have a @PreAuthorize annotation but not on the rest controller i am trying to access:i updated my question !!

Comment: On which endpoint do you get the 403 response? Do you have endpoints which works OK? Please share the full stack error with debug

Comment: on "api/users".they work fine when i remove ".authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()"

Comment: Do you use authenticated session for these requests?

Comment: i used this repo :https://github.com/sharmaritesh/oauth2-spring-boot-mongo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234003/discussion-between-hillel-guy-and-youssef-boudaya).

Answer (score 0):

In `ResourceServerConfig` class file, in the `configure` method change to the below code.

```
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .anonymous().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll().and()
    .httpBasic();
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: it turned that i had to crypt the password and the client secret in order to login and get token

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of configuration spring security with a jwt token check   :
you can change the data source from h2 to mongodb and find the filters and providers used in my repo :

```
https://github.com/e2rabi/sbs-user-management/tree/main/sbs-user-management



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
             // Put your public API here 
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"),

    );
    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

    TokenAuthenticationProvider provider;

    SecurityConfig(final TokenAuthenticationProvider provider) {
        super();
        this.provider = requireNonNull(provider);
    }


   @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                // this entry point handles when you request a protected page and you are not yet
                // authenticated
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();

                // h2 console config
                http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
                // disable page caching
                http.headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Bean
    TokenAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
        return successHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean disableAutoRegistration(final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: it turned that i had to crypt the password and the client secret in order to login and get token

Comment: I see you're securing your apis using oauth2 authorization code workflow

Comment: my solution was  for a jwt bearer token authentication

Answer (score -1):

Hope that my answer can help,
you can drop a breakpoint to the line change the response status, and then check who and why it returns 403, it can finally help you get the solution

> 1. Drop a breakpoint on the line set the 403 status, to see how this happen from the stackframes.
>
> Guess that it returns 403 without much other information, but it must need to set the status to the response, right? So drop a breakpoint to the setStatus method, I don't know where it should locate, in tomcat lib, spring lib, or servlet lib. Check the HttpResponse, they're several implementation, set the breakpoints for those setStatus/setCode methods. (Next you can see it acutally happens at HttpResponseWrapper::setStatus)
>
> 2. Analyze the stackframes to see what's going on there

please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577697/4033979

Comment: OK, updated. ..