# Spring security 403 with disabled csrf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, http-status-code-403

Using spring security, I've looked at similar questions but they say to try disable cors & csrf.

I am using it on the browser so I will need csrf. But just testing briefly doesn't change the outcome.

On login I get an access token and refresh token.

Using this token gives me a 403 forbidden response code.

My configuration is the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET, "/**").hasAnyAuthority("STUDENT");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()));
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

I think maybe its something to do with this filter but if I change `forbidden.value` to something else the result is still `forbidden.value`

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter { // INTERCEPTS EVERY REQUEST
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getServletPath().equals("/login")){ filterChain.doFilter(request,response); } // DO NOTHING IF LOGGING IN
        else{
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
            if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
                try {
                    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length()); // TAKES TOKEN STRING AND REMOVES BEARER
                    // THIS NEEDS MAKING SECURE AND ENCRYPTED vvvvvvv
                    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes()); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build(); // USING AUTH0
                    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
                    String email = decodedJWT.getSubject(); // GETS EMAIL
                    String[] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class); // GETS ROLES
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    stream(roles).forEach(role -> {  authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role)); }); // CONVERTS ALL USERS ROLE INTO AN AUTHORITY
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null); // PASSWORD IS NULL AT THIS POINT
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken); // INSERTS TOKEN INTO CONTEXT // THIS SHOWS AUTHENTICATED FALSE, DETIALS FALSE AND GRANTED AUTHORITIES EMPTY
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response); // GETS TO THIS LINE HERE
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    response.setHeader("error" , e.getMessage() );
                    response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());
                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                    error.put("error_message", e.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error); // THEN SKIPS RIGHT TO THIS LINE HERE EVEN IF BREAKPOINTING BEFORE
                }
            }
            else{ filterChain.doFilter(request, response); }
        }
    }
}
```

debugging shows it hits `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` then jumps straight to the exception catch `objectMapper` line

The user submitting is also of the Student role.

Comment: I would not recommend writing custom security as it is bad practice. Also using JWTs as sessions is also quite dangerous as in you cant logout the user.

Comment: @Toerktumlare It is part of the guide i am following. Do you have any suggestions on how to go about using the default doing then?

I need jwt as it will be the easiest implement on my frontend

Comment: by using regular formLogin with session cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line
`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null);`

is missing authorities:

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null, authorities);`

Answer (score 0):

Hope that my answer can help,
you can drop a breakpoint to the line change the response status, and then check who and why it returns 403, it can finally help you get the solution

> 1. Drop a breakpoint on the line set the 403 status, to see how this happen from the stackframes.
>
> Guess that it returns 403 without much other information, but it must need to set the status to the response, right? So drop a breakpoint to the setStatus method, I don't know where it should locate, in tomcat lib, spring lib, or servlet lib. Check the HttpResponse, they're several implementation, set the breakpoints for those setStatus/setCode methods. (Next you can see it acutally happens at HttpResponseWrapper::setStatus)
>
> 2. Analyze the stackframes to see what's going on there

please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577697/4033979